# Is there a difference between using a Cat 6 wall jack vs using a female-to-female connector?

Tags: ethernet, cable, rj-45, cat6

I am running new Cat 6 cable from my router to my office so I can get my computer hardwired instead of using Wi-Fi. When looking at what I need to get to connect the cable to a wall plate, I’m seeing 2 main options:

Option 1, which seems to be more common, is to get what I believe is called a Cat 6 wall jack:

[image: Cat 6 wall jack.]

Option 2 is to get a female-to-female wall connector:

[image: Female-to-female wall connector.]

Option 2 seems like it would be simpler, as I wouldn’t need to actually wire the cable itself to the jack; I simply plug it in. Is there an advantage to using a wall jack and doing my own wiring?

Note that I do already have some RJ45 connectors and a crimping tool for them; so if I need to cut the ethernet cable down to a shorter size; that's not an issue.

Comment: I dont know if I missed it? Are you drilling a hole through the wall?  a new hole or existing one?  Do you plan on leaving the home anytime , wherin a more professional job (even unnessisary) would effect the equity of the home, the return of a deposit, or just cover up a gaping hole in the wall for asthetics :-)   Yes I have done it, but I did hide it behind a wall plate anyways .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is clearly technically superior.

In-wall cabling should use solid core cables, while patch leads use stranded cables.  (Solid cables provide a better signal, stranded cables are flexible).

**You generally should punch down solid core cables, and crimp stranded cables.**

That said, all else being equal, by using option 1, you are reducing the number of joins (by 1 join per strand), and thus increasing the quality.

In practice, both methods will provide you with a connection - which will most likely be faster then your Internet connection anyway, but "doing it right" might give you better performance - moreso at higher speeds.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, It all depends on the installer and what tools you have available. With option 1, you're going to need a Punch Down tool, and with option 2 (which you already said you had) you need a crimping tool.

[image]

For example when it comes to cat 6. I've talked to installers that simply can't stand crimping cat 6 with RJ45 connectors because it just takes way too long during big jobs. They use option 1 even though it essentially costs more per connector. They can justify it with time saved from work hours over the long run.

If you're asking which method is better. Test it for yourself. Run the Cat 6 cable and connect the cable to option 1 & 2 and test a file transfer. I'm pretty sure it's going to be the same thing as long as you didn't make a mistake during crimping. And make sure you keep the twists of each pair as close as possible to the edge of the connection.

> Is there an advantage to using a wall jack and doing my own wiring?

I'm going to assume, when you say "my own wiring", you're referring to using a crimper with RJ45 connectors.

If that's the case, You can use a professional looking wall plate in either situation.

Option 1

[image]

Option 2

[image]

As you can see, either way works.